# Grabbing variable from Mysql and putting in email body within a loop

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

So I have a loop that is sending out email to all records where `hours_left <= .5`.

Using: `$sql = 'SELECT first_name, email, last_emailed FROM clients WHERE hours_left <= .5';` I'm grabbing which emails to send to.

On line 4, I would think that I would set the body there so it could say something like: "hello `<first_name>`, check this out." But I'm not sure how to access the `first_name` so the body changes with each go around. I'm new to php, the more easily explained for a dummy like me would be great.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
var_dump($row);
$mail->addAddress($row['email'], $row['first_name']);
$mail->Body = "hello" ; // <----this is where I'm clueless
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
    break; //Abandon sending
} else {
    echo "Message sent to :" . $row['first_name'] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row['email']) . ')<br />';

    //preapre statement safer way of updating shit
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE clients SET last_emailed = ? WHERE email = ?"))) {
       echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->bind_param('ss', $today, $row['email'])) {
       echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
// Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
$mail->clearAddresses();
}
```

I had trouble trying to verbalize exactly what I should google, so now I am here. Oh, I'm also using PHPMailer, and I'm getting things to send and access the db, everything is working aside from figuring out how to insert peoples `first_name` of who would be receiving this message.

Comment: `$name = $row['first_name']; $mail->Body = "hello $name" ;` - Try that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I would be setting that variable outside/before of the while loop right?

Comment: are you sending every user the same message? No customizations?

Comment: good point @bassxzero . I'm sending them the same message, but it just needs to say their name, and how many hours they have left. I'm pretty sure freds method will work but with just a slight modification: `$name = $row['first_name']; $mail->Body = "hello " . $name` and I put all this inside the while loop.

Comment: that's exactly what you should do. I figured you'd know that I meant for you to use that in the loop and that answer below is a carbon copy of what I said for you to do

Comment: Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). It doens't show how to customise the body, but it has a more efficient structure than you are using. Preparing that statement every time around the loop is a waste of time - the whole purpose of prepared statements is to avoid that!

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this line:**

```
$mail->Body = "hello" ; // <----this is where I'm clueless
```

**with:**

```
$mail->Body = "hello {$row['first_name']}";
```

**or:**

```
$name = $row['first_name']; $mail->Body = "hello $name";
```

**or:**

```
$name = $row['first_name']; $mail->Body = "hello ".$name;
```

*PS: You have to do that inside while loop.*

Comment: I've just edited my answer to summarize alternatives mentioned in comments. If this solved your question, please mark this as [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)